# How is Github Changing Pages and the URL so smoothly without AJAX?

Tags: html, css, performance

If you go to a project on github, say https://github.com/insoshi/insoshi, and you start clicking into the folders, the folder animates to the sub-directory, and the browser URL changes, but it looks like it's all AJAX.  It's only like this in Chrome/Safari from what I've seen.

Is this a webkit transition effect?  Or is it just some serious caching/performance-optimization :)?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Github [talks about it](https://github.com/blog/760-the-tree-slider) in their blog.

Answer (score 3):

This is an AJAX based effect.  This type of sliding menu (as far as I am aware) was first used for the iPod browsing method.  I do recall a lot of CSS/JS falvoured solutions poping up when that was popular.

Then again this method could have originated somewhere else.  But yes your solution is AJAX based, you can use **FIREBUG** in Firefox to see the requests to get directory listings.

The transition effect is a slide effect.  There are various examples on the net.