# Load content with Javascript, but still retain a unique link to specific content pages

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm a web novice, so I'll start by expressing my problem in case there's a better solution than the way I'm trying to achieve it.

I've changed my site's content to by loaded dynamically through the jQuery load() function so the whole page isn't requested every time only the unique document content changes. However, I want the site to still have a way of taking users to a specific piece of content like they would if they just visited the direct address of the document via the URL (So users can be linked to specific pages of content).

I implemented this with URL parameters e.g. "&cat=1&page=2" and got them using jQuery and loaded up the correct file into the #content area. So when the user clicks a link in the navigation, it loads up the relevant content and adds the parameters of the page to the URL like the example I gave.

This is my code:

```
//Adding location params to URL when navigation link is clicked
$("#innerNavbar > ul > li > a").on('click', function(){
    var cat = $(this).parent().parent().attr('id');
    var page = $(this).attr('name');
    var path = "categories/"+cat+"/"+page+".php";
    window.location = "#?cat="+cat+"&page="+page;
    $("#content").load(path);
});

//Get URL params and load correct page
var path = "categories/";
var cat = $.getUrlVar('cat'); //External code in getURLparams.js
var page = $.getUrlVar('page');
if (cat){
    if (page){
        path = "categories/"+cat+"/"+page+".php";
    } else {
        path = "categories/"+cat+"/index.php";
    }
} else {
    path = "categories/pages/index.php";
}
$("#content").load(path);
```

The specific code I'm having problems with is this:

```
window.location = "#?cat="+cat+"&page="+page;
```

I'm using this code to add the params to the URL without reloading the page (with the # tag), however, the # will mean the page won't be reloaded if the user is already on a page with something like "#?cat=things&page=stuff" in the URL.

I may have over-complicated this, but long story short, is there a way I can add params to the URL without it sending an HTTP request/reloading the page and without using a # at the start?

And again, if there's a completely solution to the general problem I will welcome it :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How is Github Changing Pages and the URL so smoothly without AJAX?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5216314/how-is-github-changing-pages-and-the-url-so-smoothly-without-ajax)

Comment: [**History.js**](http://balupton.github.io/history.js/demo/) sounds like what you need.

Comment: You can listen to the hashchange event witch gets fired when the hashtag change in the URL: $(window).on("hashchange", _startHashChange); But i strongly recomend to have a look to some Unique Page App JS libraries, like [iris.js](https://github.com/thegameofcode/iris)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to start going down the road of using a single-page application framework, as @Alejandro González mentioned, checking for a hashchange event on window and calling a function is your best bet. Something like:

```
function processParams() {
  var params = window.location.hash;
  // do something with params
}

$(window).on('hashchange', processParams);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to achieve seems more like a Single Page Application. There are javascript libraries which can help you build the application the way you described it. 
Take a look on [Sammy.js](http://sammyjs.org/) or [History.js](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/) libraries.