# Why don't other sites/services see my hash URLs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, hash

My site has all dynamically loaded content.

I have written a few JS functions that change the content based on the URL received. If someone goes to www.mysite.com/#1056, the content for that will be loaded.

```
function getLocationHash() {
    //check if there is a location hash in the address bar, get that URL
    if (window.location.hash != '') {
        processURL()
    }
}
```

Then it calls the processURL function

```
function processURL() {
    if (window.location.hash != '') {
        urlHash = window.location.hash;

        //if it's a catalog item, it has a number above #1000
        if (urlHash > 10000) {
            getDetail(urlHash);
        }
```

This works fine for history or jumping right to a URL on the site - however, other sites cannot follow this. For instance, if I enter www.mysite.com/#1056 into Facebook status, FB scrapes only www.mysite.com index page. It does not follow through to the end of the JS. Is this because the JS is looking for the 'window' property?

Same thing with Google crawling. I set up a sitemap with all of the hashed URLs but Google only crawls the index page.

So the question is: How do I take what I have here and properly format a URL that other services like Facebook and Google can "see"?

Any tips would be much appreciated.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/getting-started

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `#` indicates the start of the fragment identifier. It is how you link to part of a page.

It is frequently abused to be read by JavaScript to load different content via Ajax, but that only works if the client runs the JS.

The scrapers used by Google and Facebook don't run JS.

1. Stop using fragment identifiers to load content
2. Use real URLs instead
3. Have the server deliver complete pages for those URLs
4. Apply your Ajax changes using [the history API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5216314/how-is-github-changing-pages-and-the-url-so-smoothly-without-ajax) to update the URI to match the one that would load the page you are creating with JS directly

Comment: '2. Use real URLs instead 3. Have the server deliver complete pages for those URLs' So are you suggesting a php solution?

Comment: A server side solution. You could use PHP if you like, but there are plenty of other options. It would only be used for initial loads and non-JS clients of course.

Comment: Just to confirm my understanding here - the page that Google or FB reads has to be served, not generated client-side - correct? So anything involving javascript, client-side generated content (whether it's a hashed url or not) will not be "seen"?

Comment: Correct. Don't make content available only via JS if you want it readable by bots.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. You say "only via JS". Since all of my code is already in JS, should I keep that for browsers and make separate code just for bots? What if the bot code is just rough HTML (images and text) w/o all of the layout info (tables, etc)? I could for instance see using php to fill a <P> tag with all of the text, parsed from the json (content) file, unformatted. Would something like that work?

Comment: Then people will get the ugly page when they arrive from a search engine. Do what I said in the answer. Have each URL give a complete page. If you want to do Ajaxy stuff, then use JS to change the page into the same state what it would be in if you loaded that new URL from the server and use pushState to put that URL into the history.

Answer (score -1):

These are the solutions i discovered when i researched this.

For crawling there is the 'hashbang' , as described in the google pages.https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/learn-more?hl=nl

And for the linking on facebook you can for example use html5 pushstate. 
http://badassjs.com/post/840846392/location-hash-is-dead-long-live-html5-pushstate

Comment: The [hashbang approach is rather horrible](http://isolani.co.uk/blog/javascript/BreakingTheWebWithHashBangs), and obsoleted by the History API.

Comment: @Quentin I agree with you, but i thought i'd offer the resource regardless

Comment: @quentin from everything I have read it seems that twitter and FB still use the hashbang method? Is this true?

Comment: @frankie — They might use it as a fallback in ancient browsers, but neither of them use it by default today. Twitter [made a big show](https://blog.twitter.com/2012/improving-performance-twittercom) of getting rid of them because of the performance penalties that came from loading a default page and then overwriting the whole thing with new content loaded with JS.

Comment: @frankie i know that grooveshark still uses it.