# How to determine what content is active on a page

Tags: html, encode

I am at a bit of loss of knowledge and honestly don't know what to search for. What I need to be able to do is determine what content to show on a webpage that way when I refresh it will not reset everything. For example, if someone clicks on the messages tab I want the browser to know when it refreshes, that is the tab to stay on. I believe this is done through url encoding but I am not sure. Any help would be AWESOME! Thanks fellow coders.

MORE INFO: I have 2 buttons on a page. One is named "home" and when I click it I want the content of the home page to appear in a box named "info-main". I am doing this with ajax requests. When I click on "edit profile", I want the content in div id "info-main" to be replaced with the edit profile information that is retrieved via ajax as well. I need to figure out how if someone refreshes the page... I want it to stay showing the edit profile information rather then going back to the default of "home" content.

MORE INFO(AGAIN)
I just had a great idea. When the page refreshes, I want it to load specific ajax code based on what the url encode is.

For example.... if the url is:

http://www.exampleurl.com/index.php?info=status-load

I want the browser to execute the ajax I have for retrieving status's.

OR

If the url is:

http://www.exampleurl.com/index.php?info=edit-prof

I want it to load the ajax code I have for retrieving profile edit info.

I really hope this helps. :/

Comment: some more info would be nice... like, my guess, you are using something like Bootstrap on a website, and you would like to link to a specific tab on a page. But, I don't know if that's the case or not

Comment: added for info. Thanks for your help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How is Github Changing Pages and the URL so smoothly without AJAX?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5216314/how-is-github-changing-pages-and-the-url-so-smoothly-without-ajax)

Comment: not a duplicate. I am using ajax on my own site. Just need a way to reference the ajax.

Answer (score 0):

The way I do it is I place a # before the link i.e. href="#messages"

Then I link a .js with this code.

```
$(function () {
var hash = location.hash
  , hashPieces = hash.split('?')
  , activeTab = $('[href=' + hashPieces[0] + ']');
activeTab && activeTab.tab('show');
});
```

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

For referring an element on your page, you use a link with a hashtag.
For example, if you have a layout like this:

```
<div class="top-nav">
    <a href="/">Home</a>
    <a href="/editProfile">Edit Profile</a>
</div>
```

And you have a password edit form on your `editProfile` page, you can like to it like this:

```
    <a href="/editProfile#passwordChange">Edit Profile</a>
```

if you have a `<form id="passwordChange">` on your `editProfile`.

Read more: http://css-tricks.com/hash-tag-links-padding/