# how to load pages in a div and change the url?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a webpage like this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/javpz/)

I want to load the clicked page in a `div`, and I want to change the displayed url in the browser to the loaded page url, as follow:

if the user clicked page 1: the page 1 will load in the pages div and url should be displayed as this (for example): mywebsite.com/page1.html instead of mywebsite.com/index.html
so the url should be changed when a page is loaded.

Comment: You'd be wanting to use iframes for this -- And javascript to listen for the onClick events and to add the iframe. But i wouldn't recommend them - Click [here](http://moz.com/community/q/iframes-seo) for a little info as to why they're a bad idea for SEO.

Comment: scratch "want to change the displayed url in the browser" requirement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To spoof the URL, check out this question: [How is Github Changing Pages and the URL so smoothly without AJAX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5216314/how-is-github-changing-pages-and-the-url-so-smoothly-without-ajax) as well as the resource linked in it: https://github.com/blog/760-the-tree-slider

You can't load a web page itself in to a div. You could use AJAX to load the contents of a page and then put that in to the div. In this case, the pages you would be loading would have to be fragments (i.e., no `DOCTYPE`, `<html>`, `<head>`, or `<body>` tags). You could alternatively just have them be dynamic pages, which would go along with what I said about the URL.

If you want to do the AJAX bit, you would:

1. Build the main page
2. Build the page fragments
3. Override some/all of the anchor elements (links)
4. Perform the AJAX

For simplicity of this example, I'm going to assume you are using jQuery for the AJAX calls. It is certainly possible to write AJAX without any third-party libraries, but the code is longer. If you wish to do this, it's pretty easy to google for a decent tutorial.

**Build the main page**

First up, the main page. This would be a full page with the div you want to override. For simplicity, I'm going to give it an ID named "content".

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Demo</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content"><a href="page1.html">Go to page 1</a></div>
</body>
```

The default contents of `content` just has a link to page1.

**Build the page fragment**

A page fragment can be anything. For simplicity, we'll call it "page1.html" and it just contains:

```
 <p>Hello World</p>
```

Override some/all of the anchor elements (links)

Now, we need to add an event listener to prevent the normal action from occurring when you click a link. For this example, we'll override any anchors in `content`. Also, we'll use jQuery.

```
$('#content a').click(function(e) { 
    loadPage($(this).attr('href'));
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

This does two things. First, it calls the function we'll implement to do the actual loading. Then, it prevents the anchor from doing it's normal thing of taking them to the next page.

** Perform the AJAX **

Last step, we need to implement loadPage which will do what we want.

```
function loadPage(url) {
   $.ajax({
       url: url
   }).done(function(data) {
       $('#content').html(data);
   });
}
```

And that's it. It'll take the URL we put in the anchor, load that file (which is our page fragment) and put the contents in `content` when it is done.

Like I said, it won't change the URL. To do that, you'd have to implement traditional dynamic web page stuff.

Comment: "You can't "spoof" the URL with something else" — Not been true for about half a decade (see duplicate question).

Comment: Cool, I wasn't aware of that. Learn something new every day. I still kind of consider it bad practice in general, so I doubt I'll be doing it. Nice to know I could though if I had a legitimate use though. Updated my answer to share that information.