# Htaccess with anchor (#)

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have some problems to put anchor (#) into my htaccess file !

I have this code:

```
RewriteRule ^(\w+)\/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)\%23([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)$ view.php?snip=$1&msg=$2&google=$3 [R,NE]
```

But when i try to get index google with `$_GET['google']` i get error that said: Undefined index GOOGLE.

I seen lot of websites use this trick for the urls, and one of them are FACEBOOK, i want integrate this style to my website.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can't `.htaccess` this. It's called a hashbang (The `/#!/`). It's javascript handling it, not the server (well, at least the first step)

Comment: It's a [fragment identifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier) and it doesn't get passed to the server (back-end code).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fragment identifier references the id of an element in an HTML document. It is handled purely client side and never send to the server.

You can't use it in the left hand side of a server side redirect rule.

---

They have been abused to describe content that should be loaded from other URLs using JavaScript. This has been [problematic](http://isolani.co.uk/blog/javascript/BreakingTheWebWithHashBangs) but superseded by [the history API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history) as used, for example, by [Github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5216314/how-is-github-changing-pages-and-the-url-so-smoothly-without-ajax).

You said that you saw Facebook using this trick, they have given up on it in favour of using the history API. (It is possible that they use the hash hack as a fallback on ancient browsers, their marketshare is sufficiently small that I would advise letting them failover to the non-ajax version of the site instead).

Comment: Thank you for all this informations :) very usefull